# Hibernate-Map to different table based on field value

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql

Is it possible to get hibernate to auto-partition the underlying database based on a field value?

To clarify, Imagine I have a class that represents diagnostic readings for cars. I get a new reading every n seconds. i want to store the data for each type of car in a different table.

Now here is the kicker, I may want to remove a type of car altogether in the future (or ignore it/stop getting data) or possibly add one.

I am not stuck with hibernate but i want a solution that would create a new table based on the car type whenever a new type is detected.

It should be automatic, i would not want to have to manually go into the database and create a new "shard" each time.

Comment: Can't you just add a trigger to your DB to listen type changes and create (or remove) necessary table?

Comment: wouldnt that be a sever performance hit? I am doing a lot of inserts

Comment: I think the **types** table trigger is safe. Guess you don't add a new type every second